# ASINetworkQueue inside NSOperation blocking main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, nsoperation

I'm using an `NSOperation` to collect data that should be downloaded (takes 2-5 sec.) and afterwards I download this. I've put a ASINetworkQueue inside this NSOperation to start downloading the previously collected data.

Everything works fine but when I call `cancelAllOperations` on my `ASINetworkQueue`, the main thread blocks and the UI Freezes. Why is this happening? Everything else works fine.

Here is my Code:

```
- (void)main {
    //ManagedObjectContext for operations
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];


    [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    // Register context with the notification center
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:self.managedObjectContext];


    [self startDownload];


    if (!self.downloadDidFail) {
        [self moveFiles];

        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }
}

- (void)startDownload {    
    self.downloadQueue = [ASINetworkQueue queue];
    self.downloadQueue.delegate = self;
    [self.downloadQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(dataRequestFailed:)];
    [self.downloadQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(dataRequestFinished:)];
    [self.downloadQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(dataQueueFinished:)];
    [self.downloadQueue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:YES];
    [self.downloadQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:self.progressView];

    for (File *dataFile in self.dataFiles) {
            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataFile.url]];
            [request setDownloadDestinationPath:dataFile.path];

            [self.downloadQueue addOperation:request];
        }
    }

    [self.downloadQueue go];
    [self.downloadQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}

- (void)dataRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"DL finished");
}

- (void)dataRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    DLog(@"Download failed");

    self.downloadDidFail = YES;
}

- (void)dataQueueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue {
    DLog(@"Finished Data Queue");
}

- (void)cancelDownload {
    self.canceledDownload = YES;

    [self.downloadQueue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

Comment: It seems an unusual pattern to put an `ASINetworkQueue` (a subclass of `NSOperationQueue`) inside an `NSOperation`.

Comment: Unusual, maybe, but is it wrong? I think it's the cleanest solution to my problem. Loading the requests and download them afterwards. The reason why I'm doing it like this is because there are a lot of Requests that must be created and loading file names that should be downloaded takes about 3-4 sec

Comment: Personally I'd use one queue, and then have the initial `NSOperation` add operations to the same queue, rather than create another one. Can you show us the code you use to set up your `ASINetworkQueue`?

Comment: But I need the `ASIHTTPNetworkQueue` because I need to show the overall progress.

Comment: I'd still create the queue outside the NSOperation, since I think it would be cleaner. In any case, I think we need to see how you're setting up the queue to see if there's anything there that might be causing your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASI requests responses and queue responses are deliberately moved to the main thread for library design purposes.
You have two solution:
-Subclass ASIHTTPRequest and overwrite 2 methods. (Look for in the code something like "subclass for main thread").
-Modify the library. (Easy, but personally I don't like this solution).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved by calling:

```
[queue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO]
```

before calling:

```
[queue cancelAllOperations].
```

Comment: Interesting! I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

What does your failure delegate method do? ASIHTTPRequest will run that on the main thread by default, so if it does a lot of processing (or there are a lot of requests) this could take quite some time.

Comment: It's only setting a BOOL variable. This can't be the problem because I've removed this part. I've just tested the same without a NSOperation and the same problem is happening. The UI freezes until all requests are canceled. I'm talking about 120 requests that have to be canceled, but that should not be the problem or am I wrong?

Comment: Try running in the instruments profiler tool and figure out what is actually happening on the main thread when the delay happens. Possibly you could also try unsetting the delegate for the queue & for each request before cancelling the requests.